# Difference between Groovy 1.6 and 1.8

Tags: java, groovy

We have recently upgraded an application in which we have our own embedded Groovy code to trigger certain things. Previously the application had the Groovy 1.6 library and since upgrading now uses the 1.8 library. However this is where we run into problems, certain pieces of code now do not run and they generally have the error:

```
    System exception occurred: class=class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Are there fundamental differences in the code I should be looking for? Or anywhere that there is a list of differences between the 2 libraries.

Thanks in Advance

Edit to include trace:

```
    Groovy Job Inbound is Failed.
    System exception occurred: class=class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, 
    message=Inbound
    Inbound (compact stack trace follows)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    com.application.argo.util.CustomGroovyInvoker.invokeCustomGroovy(CustomGroovyInvoker.java:51)
    com. application.argo.business.GroovyJobManagerPea$1.doInTransaction(GroovyJobManagerPea.java:76)
    com. application.framework.persistence.hibernate.PersistenceTemplate.invoke(PersistenceTemplate.java:137)
    com. application.argo.business.GroovyJobManagerPea.executeGroovy(GroovyJobManagerPea.java:70)
    com. application.argo.business.GroovyJobManagerPea.executeGroovyPlugin(GroovyJobManagerPea.java:56)
    com. application.framework.persistence.hibernate.PersistenceInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceInterceptor.java:131)
    com. application.argo.portal.job.GroovyJob.executeGroovyPlugin(GroovyJob.java:99)
    com. application.argo.portal.job.GroovyJob.executeTargetTask(GroovyJob.java:83)
    com. application.argo.portal.job.AbstractJob.executeInternal(AbstractJob.java:71)
    com. application.framework.quartz.InterruptableQuartzJobBean.execute(InterruptableQuartzJobBean.java:50), root cause=class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException / Inbound.
```

Comment: I'm sure that a complete stacktrace would help

Comment: The release notes of which Dave? The application or the Groovy?

Comment: @reto I have added the trace.

Comment: Is there any logging that gives you a clue as to which class is not found? How did you do the upgrade?  Do you have GROOVY_HOME set?

Comment: Hi @tim_yates basically the application manufacturer sent us an upgrade and informed us that the libraries were upgraded to 1.8. The application speaks with a database where the above code is stored. when trying to run the Groovy the error as shown in the trace is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a huge difference between (org.codehaus.) Groovy 1.6 and 1.8. I remember when I upgraded from 1.6 to 1.7, and again from 1.7 to 1.8, and neither were pleasant activities, involving lots of little code changes to get things working again. So it's likely you need to change your embedded Groovy code to make it work.